# Renaming columns using `lapply` and `dplyr` in `R` in nested lists

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, lapply

I have been applying the function on nested lists as follows.

```
myfiles1a <- lapply(myfiles1a, function(x) {rename(x, "China" = "CHINA2"); x})
```

But I get the following error.

```
Error in rename(x, China = "CHINA2") : unused argument (China = "CHINA2")
```

Comment: `dplyr::rename()` uses "new_name = old_name" pairs. Are you using the names in the right order? (plus, you shouldn't need any quotes around the names)
Furthermore: your function returns x without changing it. If you want it to return the renamed dataframe, you can remove `; x` from your function.

Comment: The order of names is correct. Quotes removed and also `; x` removed. Same situation. Nothing happens and Error returned.

Comment: In that case, you might have to provide us with a reproducible example that includes how myfiles1a was created (or if that is not feasible, and minimal reproducible example with made up data).
One more question: are you sure you are using `dplyr::rename()` ? To me, that error message looks like you might be using `plyr::rename()` instead...

Comment: Bingo! You got it right. Bro. The issue was `dplyr::rename()`. Thanks a lot. I was using `plyr` to flatten the nested list by `ldply`. Can it be done with `dplyr` so as to avoid this mistake?